# Selecting the leaf of jtree that will open another jrame in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe, jtree

Good day,
I am trying to create a tree view in order to display for the user the other j Frames in Netbeans. 
When the user select a leaf, it will display for him  the required forum.

What I am facing right now that when selecting the other leaves, it is display for me all forums. 
[image: this is the tree view]
[image: here after selecting the node training and it is the same when selecting recruitment]

Here is my codes

```
private void jTree1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)
     jTree1.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
     if (node == null) return;
     Object nodeInfo = node.getUserObject();
     jTree1.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode
     (TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
    JTree tree = new JTree();
     Employee emp = new Employee();
     rectutment rec = new rectutment();
     interview inter = new interview();        
     DefaultMutableTreeNode firstLeaf = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode)tree.getModel().getRoot()).getFirstLeaf();
     tree.setSelectionPath(new TreePath(firstLeaf.getPath()));
     DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) tree.getModel();
     DefaultMutableTreeNode root = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();
     root.add(firstLeaf);
     firstLeaf.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode("firstleaf"));
            model.reload();
            emp.add(tree);
            emp.pack();
            emp.setVisible(true);
           if ( emp.isActive()&& rec.isActive()){
           emp.dispose();
       }
       else{
           rec.dispose();
       }  
  rec.setDefaultCloseOperation(emp.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  rec.setLocationRelativeTo(emp);
  rec.add(tree);
  rec.pack();
  rec.setVisible(true);        
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you take a look at the [JavaDocs for `JTree`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html) it actually has a basic example of what you need

Comment: I checked but I can't find what is suitable for my program

Comment: The example below *"If you are interested in detecting either double-click events or when a user clicks on a node, regardless of whether or not it was selected, we recommend you do the following:"* is where you need to start